# Which lots do I need in a neighbourhood in order to have all the features from all expansions?

Tags: the-sims-3

Nearly every expansion adds community lots that need to be in your town in order to be able to access all the features of that expansion: dog & cat parks for Pets, bars for Nightlife, etc.

Where can I get a list of all the lot types needed in order to have access to every feature, as well as all the careers and rabbitholes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rabbitholes are as follows:

- Abandoned warehouse
- Arboretum
- Bistro
- Bookstore
- City Hall
- Diner
- Equestian Center
- Film Studio
- Gypsy Caravan
- Hospital
- Mausoleum
- Military Base
- Office Building
- Police Department
- School
- Science Lab
- Skydiving Center
- Spa
- Stadium
- Supermarket
- Theatre
- Vault of Antiquity

([Source: The Sims Wiki](http://sims.wikia.com/wiki/Rabbit_hole))

Many of them only supply jobs, but if you're counting that as a "feature", then you need all of them.